# Multiple Icons From One Install?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to create two icons (that link to different functionality) for a single install form the app store?

For example, on Android, when you install Google Maps, you get Maps and Navigation.  Ideally, both "apps" would have access to the same data, but each icon would link to different and separate functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at this time (but I could imagine this happening down the road, if they port PackageMaker to doing iPhone apps).

The user authorizes one signed app to be downloaded and installed and only one icon (for one package) appears.

One way to get around this would be to have two separate apps but both apps call into the same framework (or library or common sourcebase) for whatever functionality is common between the two.

Comment: Would this require more than one install from the app store?

Comment: It would. You could check if the other app is installed, and if it's not, display a message and a link.